# EFS file availability inconsistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, unix, nfs

I'm having trouble with AWS EFS. I have two machines A & B, both ec2 instances, that mount the same efs volume. When I create and write to a file on machine A, I can't write to the same file on machine B until I've read or ls'd the file.

The file is written to /var/log/access.log & /var/log is mounted on efs

Machine A creates and writes to /var/log/access.log

The user on machine B doesnt have permission to create new files in /var/log. So the user sees a permission denied error when trying to write to the file. Eg

```
15:35 ~ $ echo > /var/log/access.log
bash: /var/log/access.log: Permission denied
```

This behaviour continues until the user either ls's or reads the file. Then they can write to the file

I've tried to remove the nfs caching from both machines with `mount -o sync`, also flushing the caches with `sync`